# PHP URL GET Charset Issues

Tags: php, url, character-encoding, get

I'm building a filebrowser in PHP by using URL Parameters and I'm having problems with some special chars.
I managed to translate `ß` into `%26` and `'` into `%2C` and as expected my R'n'B folder outputs R%2Cn%2CB as but PHP says

> Warning: opendir(dir//Musik/R,n,B/,dir//Musik/R,n,B/) [function.opendir]: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (code: 2)

My code snippet:

```
function fileBrowser($dir, $file) {
    $trans = array("&" => "%26","'" => "%2C");
    $cdir = strtr(@$_GET['dir'],$trans);
    $cfile = strtr($file,$trans);
...
```

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: There is [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) for that. But are you generating an URL now, or are you trying to access it using PHPs file functions? (If so, no URL encoding is required.)

Comment: Thanks but my question is answered now.

Comment: Google "php unicode filename" and you will get some interesting results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use urlencode/urldecode instead replace it by your self.

However `ß` is `%C3%9F` and `'` is `%27`